# Бесплатная библиотека для работы с *.DOCX

Tags: c#, .net, поиск-библиотек, docx

Посоветуйте бесплатную и хорошо документированную библиотеку для работы с *.DOCX.

Знаю, что есть OpenXML, но что есть в природе удобного помимо него?

Например, для Excel есть удобная EpPlus.

Comment: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/how-programmatically-0b9e250a

Answer (score 6):

**DocX**

[Git](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/DocX)

Exp:

```
DocX doc= DocX.Create(filePath);
Paragraph p1 = template.InsertParagraph();
p1.AppendLine("This line contains a ").Append("bold").Bold().Append(" word.");
p1.AppendLine("Here is example with question mark?");
p1.AppendLine();
p1.AppendLine("Can you help me figure it out?");
p1.AppendLine();
```

Очень проста в использовании.

Answer (score 4):

Есть такая open-source С++ библиотека [DocxFactory](http://docxfactory.com/free-download/) для генерации DOCX документов. Для неё в том числе есть обертка для C#. Прикладываю ссылку на [туториал](http://docxfactory.com/free-download/). Судя по документации, основной функционал работы она поддерживает(сам не пробовал использовать на проектах). В документации имеются куски примеров по работе с DOCX. 
 Также ссылка на [github-проект](http://docxfactory.com/tutorial/).

Если требуется, можно попробовать создать какой-то экзампел.

Answer (score 4):

**Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word**

Как известно, Microsoft Word является COM-объектом, т.е. спроектирован таким образом, что позволяет другим программам подключаться к себе и управлять им. Программно можно проделать практически все операции, которые мы делаем вручную в Word: создать новый документ, внести в него правки, сохранить его и т.п. Но для ее работы требуется лицензия MS Office на каждом клиентском компьютере. Кроме того, MS Office загружается в фоновом режиме, вследствие чего занимает определенное количество оперативной памяти и загружает большое количество файлов и DLL. Приложения MS Office были разработаны как приложения для пользовательского интерфейса, и поэтому Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word работает очень медленно. Microsoft не рекомендует использовать Office Automation (или любой Office Interop) на сервере.

**DocumentFormat.OpenXml**

Open XML SDK предоставляет инструменты для работы с документами Office Word, Excel и PowerPoint. Он поддерживает такие сценарии, как заполнение содержимого в файлах Word из источника данных XML, разделение (измельчение) файла Word или PowerPoint на несколько файлов и объединение нескольких файлов Word, поиск и замена контента с использованием регулярных выражений. Но при присвоении некоторого стиля, в свойствах предоставляется только идентификатор предоставленого стиля, а сам стиль описывается отдельно в файле style.xml. В результате необходимости регулярного сопоставления ID стиля с контейнером style.xml для получения характеристик стилей абзацев, возрастает сложность программного использования библиотеки. [link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/)

**Spire.Doc**

Spire.Doc для .NET - это полностью независимая библиотека классов .NET Word, специально созданная для разработчиков, которая позволяет быстро генерировать, открывать, писать, редактировать и сохранять документы Word не требует установки в систему каждого пользователя MS Office, то есть возможность полностью независимой от него работы; объемная документация с примерами и пояснениями. Работать с библиотекой достатосно удобно. Однако полная версия Spire.Doc не является бесплатной, а бесплатная версия, FreeSpire.Doc, имеет определенные ограничения (например обработка не более 500 абзацев и 25 таблиц). [link](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/word-for-net-introduce.html#.WtUVnYjFLtR)

Comment: Более подробно  на странице 61 http://journals.khnu.km.ua/vestnik/pdf/tech/pdfbase/2018/2018_1/(257)%202018-1-t.pdf